# Cmder seems to not emulate PowerShell when using Vagrant

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, vagrant, cmder

I'd like to provision and connect to virtual machine using Vagrant and Cmder. Unfortunately, when I try to `vagrant up` my machine, I'm getting error that I don't use Power Shell:

```
λ  vagrant up
5
Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

The version of powershell currently installed on this host is less than
the required minimum version. Please upgrade the installed version of
powershell to the minimum required version and run the command again.

  Installed version: N/A
  Minimum required version: 3
```

What I tried so far was:

1. Choose Power Shell type of terminal (both default and admin mode)
2. Run cmder as Administrator and try again (1)
3. Try solution [Cmder Powershell ignores profiles](https://superuser.com/questions/956182/cmder-powershell-ignores-profiles)
4. Try solution [How do I update Cmder to use PowerShell Core](https://superuser.com/questions/1284987/how-do-i-update-cmder-to-use-powershell-core)

Any ideas what else I can do? I use Windows 10 and with normal windows cmd I can manage of vagrant withou issues, although cmd is not Powershell

When I run `$PSVersionTable` (in PowerShell mode) I get following result:

```
λ  $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.18362.1593
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.18362.1593
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

But I need to mention that in the same mode when trying to run vagrant commands, the error still appears.

Comment: _before_ you run the vagrant command ... what do you get from running `$PSVersionTable` in the cmder console? please add that info to your Question so that everyone can see it immediately.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I just upgraded to latest version of Cmder and facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, updated the console to the latest release, and opened as admin. It works. At least for me ..

Comment: You might need to add some detail to your answer, otherwise it might get flagged.